# How to get an instance to existing AutoNumeric.js input by id?

Tags: jquery

I have one correctly initialized AutoNumeric.js instance on a page ("ok" alert)

```
<input type="text" id="id1" value="23332" data-money="true" />

 $("[data-money]").each(function(ndx, lmnt) {
   new AutoNumeric(lmnt, {
     decimalCharacterAlternative: '&',
     unformatOnSubmit: true,
     digitGroupSeparator: ' ',
     minimumValue: 0,
     modifyValueOnWheel: false,
   });
 });

 var lmnt = $('#id1').get(0);
 if (AutoNumeric.test(lmnt)) {
    alert('ok');
 }
```

How can I get an instance to this object by id (to set data and to do other operations)?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the instance of the AutoNumeric element with `$("#id")`

```
new AutoNumeric($("#testInput")[0]);

$("#testInput").on("input", function(e) {
    $("#result").text($(this).val());
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xjg0ryc4/

Answer (score 0):

I did it in the end like this:

```js
var jqInput = $("#testInput");
var anInput = new AutoNumeric(jqInput[0], 'euro');
jqInput.data('autonumeric', anInput);

// and then later wherever:
var retrievedAnInput = $("#testInput").data('autonumeric');
```